# Python modules, referencing other modules within the same package?

Tags: python, module, package

I've got a simple python package with the following directory structure:

```
wibble
|
|-----foo
|      |----ping.py
|
|-----bar
|      |----pong.py
```

Simple question: How would I reference a function / class in `ping.py` from `pong.py`? Looking through the documentation, this appears to be as simple as creating `__init__.py` files in the root of `wibble`, `foo` and `bar` and then from `pong.py` doing something like `from wibble.foo.ping import important_function`. However, trying this leads to `No module named wibble.foo.ping`.

I'm sure I've missed something in the documentation somewhere, because this must be possible to do. I'm also a little hazy on the differentiation between a `module` and a `namespace`, my background is c#.net, so any analogies here will be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add wibble to python path (see [the official documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)), one way is

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/wibble')
```

Another way is with the environment variable PYTHONPATH

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/wibble
```

Comment: On Windows, so it would be `PATH=%PATH%;c:\path\to\wibble` (Just guessing because of c#.net reference.)

Comment: I should have said - this is being developed on *nix. My concern about this solution is that it hard-ties the absolute location of the package to the codebase / infrastructure. Given that these files are easily locatable relative to each other, why can't `pong` know that it's in the `wibble` package and then locate `ping` that way?

Comment: You can dinamicly guess the location of pong.py file and add the wibble folder to python path, but definetly that is a bad practice

Comment: if you use something like setup.py for your package the code will worok, but the issue here is: your folder wibble is not in the python path.

Comment: I agree that guesswork is bad practice. I'll try the `sys.path.append` approach on both `ping` and `pong`.